# Python : count string in column dataframe that belong to a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I spent a day trying to solve my problem...

I have a DataFrame that I import from CSV file. Here an example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(['{"choices": ["rougeur", "hematome","oedeme","ecoul","necrose"]}','ecoul','necrose','','oedeme'])
```

I have my list of my possible labels:

```
label_sl=['rougeur', 'hematome', 'oedeme','ecoul','extra','necrose']
```

I would like to create a new dataframe that returns:

```
rougeur hematome oedeme ecoul extra necrose
1 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0
```

I don't find the solution...
If you have an idea...

Thanks,

AL

Comment: do you really have string representation of dictionaries in the input?

Comment: Could you explain this part `'{"choices": ["rougeur", "hematome","oedeme","ecoul","necrose"]}'`? Why is it in a dictionary form? Could there be more key:value pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your values including your dictionary are actually strings, this should work:

```
(df[0].str.replace(r'[\[\]{}"]','',regex=True)
.str.strip()
.str.split('[, ]')
.explode()
.str.get_dummies()
.groupby(level=0).sum()
.reindex(label_sl,axis=1)
.fillna(0)
.astype(int))
```

Output:

```
   rougeur  hematome  oedeme  ecoul  extra  necrose
0        1         1       1      1      0        1
1        0         0       0      1      0        0
2        0         0       0      0      0        1
3        0         0       0      0      0        0
4        0         0       1      0      0        0
```

Comment: But I've a problem when I would like to apply to my real DataFrame... I don't understand why. If my column name is 'choice' should I apply this : test=(exportLS['choice'].str.replace(r'[\[\]{}"]','',regex=True)
.str.strip()
.str.split('[, ]')
.explode()
.str.get_dummies()
.groupby(level=['choice']).sum()
.reindex(label_sl,axis=1)
.fillna(0)
.astype(int))

Comment: `code` test=(exportLS['choice'].str.replace(r'[\[\]{}"]','',regex=True)
.str.strip()
.str.split('[, ]')
.explode()
.str.get_dummies()
.groupby(level=['choice']).sum()
.reindex(label_sl,axis=1)
.fillna(0)
.astype(int)) `code`

Comment: exportLS is the name of my dataframe (previously named df)

Comment: Oh shame on me !!! groupby(level=0) !!!

Comment: Again, thanks a lot, you are very strong !

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression `\bsomething\b` extracts `something` as a separate word. We can use it like this:

```
for x in label_sl:
    df[x] = df.iloc[:,0].str.contains("\\b" + x + "\\b").astype(int)
```

where

```
label_sl=['rougeur', 'hematome', 'oedeme','ecoul','extra','necrose']
df=pd.DataFrame(['{"choices": ["rougeur", "hematome","oedeme","ecoul","necrose"]}','ecoul','necrose','','oedeme'])
```